# find unique values when comparing 2 datasets

Tags: mysql

I have the following table, called versiontrim, with some sample data:

```
version_id   trim_id
    410        3
    410        5
    410        10
    410        15
    410        20
    411        2
    411        5
    411        15
    411        25
    411        28
```

Another table, trims, holds the details for each trim_id, like follows:

```
 trim_id    trim 
    2       Air conditioner auto            
    3       Air conditioner manual
    5       Airbag
    10      Cloth seats
    25      Leather seats
    etc.....
```

I am looking to extract the unique trim_id for each SET OF 2 version_id. Result should looks like follows:

```
version_id trim_id  trim                   version_id  trim_id     trim
                                           411         2           Air conditioner auto
410        3        Air conditioner manual
410        10       Cloth seats
                                           411         25        Leather seats
410        20       blahblah
                                           411         28         blah....
etc...
```

I did manage to get each set separately using query below, swapping the version_id's:

```
SELECT version_id, trim_id, trim
FROM versiontrim a
INNER JOIN trims USING(trim_id)
WHERE a.version_id = 411
AND NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT * FROM versiontrim b 
 INNER JOIN trims USING(trim_id)
 WHERE a.trim_id = b.trim_id
 AND b.version_id = 410
)
```

I am sure there is a more straightforward way to do this, with just one query, so that I can output it properly.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which `trim_id` you want to select for each `version_id`? the `min` the `max`??

Comment: I believe this question has been asked a 100 times, but not as properly described as this one, deserves an answer though :)

Comment: Mahmoud, there is no min or max. As you may see in the example set I am looking for unique trim_id's for each version_id. Still in the example, trim_id 5 and 15 are not part of the result set, as they appear in both version_id'.

Comment: Here is the fiddle I used in my deleted response so users can try possible solutions more easily: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1c70/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 410 THEN v.version_id
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Left_Version
  ,CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 410 THEN v.trim_id
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Left_Trim_id
  ,CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 410 THEN t.trim
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Left_Trim
  ,CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 411 THEN v.version_id
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Right_Version
  ,CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 411 THEN v.trim_id
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Right_Trim_id
  ,CASE 
    WHEN v.version_id = 411 THEN t.trim
    ELSE ''
  END  AS Right_Trim
FROM(SELECT trim_id, COUNT(*)
     FROM versiontrim
     WHERE version_id IN (410,411)
     GROUP BY trim_id
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS vt
JOIN versiontrim AS v
 ON v.trim_id = vt.trim_id
   AND v.version_id IN (410,411)
JOIN trims AS t
 ON v.trim_id = t.trim_id
GROUP BY v.trim_id
ORDER BY v.trim_id;
```

Comment: Thanks AgRizzo. Works perfectly. There is a typo on last AND clause(410,410), should be (410,411). Well done, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
 version_id, trim_id, trim
FROM versiontrim a
INNER JOIN trims t on (a.trim_id=t.trim_id)
GROUP BY a.version_id, t.trim_id
```

Comment: Thanks Sashi Kant, but this does not work. Note that at some point you need to refer to specific version_id's ( 410 and 411 in the case). Table versiontrim contains zillions of version_id's and all I need is to compare a set of 2 of them.

Comment: Look if you are concerned for the view part, you should actually handle that part in the application Layer level not at the database level